# How can I change the alias of my keystore

Tags: android, keystore

I named my keystore in android studio **"nicedice"** after the app I was creating. But after I created the keystore, I relaize that I would be using that keystore for all the apps I make. I want to change the alias to **"android"**.

**How and where can I do that?**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Keystore is a file. Simply rename your keystore file to whatever you want and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it this way :

Move to

**Build --> Generate signed apk --> key alias( click button on right side(like ...) --> Select Create a new key )**

Its done